# Android Variable not passing to DB helper class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I have an app that needs to access a static database and run queries based on user input.  I am using

jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

as my Database helper class.  My main activity has 2 spinners that the user can use to narrow down a search.  The spinners return the a string variable named mGenre and mDecade respectively.  at the bottom of the activity is a button to proceed.  When the button is pushed an intent fires to bring up a new activity that displays a song title at random.  The variables are passed to the new activity vi the intent with the putExtra().  The new activity recieves the variable and uses them in if/else if statements to decide which query to run from the DB Helper.

In the DB helper class, I create an instance of the new class and us it to set the mGenre and mDecade variables so that the proper query is running, using the variables inside of the String[] args section of rawQuery().

Here is the songActivity class that is opened when the user hits the button on the Main Activity:

```
public class SongActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyDatabase db;
    private static  final String TAG = "We got ";

    String mGenre;
    String mDecade;


    public String getGenre() {
        return mGenre;
    }

    public String getDecade() {
        return mDecade;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);

        //when activity launches query database using user params

        mGenre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Genre");
        mDecade = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Decade");
        Log.v(TAG, mGenre);
        Log.v(TAG, mDecade);

        String songTitle = "";
        String songArtist = "";
        String songYear = "";

        TextView mSongTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        TextView mSongArtist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songArtist);
        TextView mSongYear = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songYear);




        db= new MyDatabase(this);




        if (mGenre.equals("*") && mDecade.equals("*")) {

            Cursor cursor = db.kamikazeSelected();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
                songYear = cursor.getString(4);
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(songTitle));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        }
        else if (!mGenre.equals("*") && mDecade.equals("*")) {
            Cursor cursor = db.genreSelected();

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
                songYear = cursor.getString(4);
//                Log.i("cursor", cursor.getString(1));
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(songTitle));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

        else if (mGenre.equals("*") && !mDecade.equals("*")) {
            Cursor cursor = db.decadeSelected();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
                songYear = cursor.getString(4);
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(songTitle));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

        else if (!mGenre.equals("*") && !mDecade.equals("*")) {
            Cursor cursor = db.bothSelected();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
                songYear = cursor.getString(4);
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(songTitle));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
        mSongTitle.setText(songTitle);
        mSongArtist.setText(songArtist);
        mSongYear.setText(songYear);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

and here is the database helper class:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static  final String TAG = "Variable for query is ";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mankiniDB.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;






    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    SongActivity mSongActivity = new SongActivity();
    String mGenre = mSongActivity.getGenre();
    String mDecade = mSongActivity.getDecade();





    public Cursor kamikazeSelected() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList ORDER BY random() limit 1", null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor genreSelected() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList WHERE Genre = ? ORDER BY random() limit 1", new String[] {mGenre});

        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor decadeSelected() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList WHERE Decade = ? ORDER BY random() limit 1", new String[] {mDecade});
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor bothSelected() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList WHERE Decade = ? AND Genre = ? ORDER BY random() limit 1", new String[] {mDecade, mGenre});

        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Here is the LogCat error stack trace:

```
03-19 21:35:54.256    1751-1751/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke I/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ successfully opened database mankiniDB.sqlite
03-19 21:35:54.260    1751-1751/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-19 21:35:54.264    1751-1751/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b61648)
03-19 21:35:54.276    1751-1751/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke.SongActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke.MyDatabase.genreSelected(MyDatabase.java:50)
            at tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke.SongActivity.onCreate(SongActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, or where I set the variables, The database helper class recives and empty variable that results in a null argument.  I need the user's input complete the query.  But it is always null.  Please help me see what I am missing.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace with the actual exception?

Comment: I have edited the post to show the log cat error.  It shows the correct method is being called, so I know the intent properly passes the variable to the songActivity class passed on the if else it statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create an `Activity` instance yourself (`new SongActivity()`), that will not work. You need to communicate with the existing `Activity` instance, for example passing it to the DB handler, although this is not recommended. The best way is to pass the needed data only, so your activity and DB handler are decoupled.

For example:

```
public Cursor genreSelected(final String genre) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList WHERE Genre = ? ORDER BY random() limit 1", new String[] {genre});
    return cursor;
}
```

Consider moving the query strings as `private static final` on your class, this makes accessing them from several parts and/or modifying them easier.

Also your handling of `Cursor` is weird. This is the proper way:

```
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
            songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
            songYear = cursor.getString(4);
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(songTitle));
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close()
    }
```

Comment: I fixed my Database Helper constructor like @dhke showed me, then using what you showed me for the corrected method, passing in the variables, and everything works as it is supposed to.  Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: I would not pass the activity to the DB helper, as I said this couples the activity and the DB handler. What if you want to do queries from another activity? Passing the Context like you did before is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfo.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        UserProfile.Users._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT," +
                        UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB + " TEXT," +
                        UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT," +
                        UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT )";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addInfo(String username, String password){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);

        long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        return rowId;
    }

    public int updateInfo(String userId, String userName, String password, String dob, String gender){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME, userName);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB, dob);

        String selection = UserProfile.Users._ID + " = ?";
        String args[] = {userId};

        int count = sqLiteDatabase.update(UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, args);

        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList readAllInfo(){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {

                UserProfile.Users._ID,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD
        };

        String sortOrder = UserProfile.Users._ID + " DESC";

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
                UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );

        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                User newUser = new User();

                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users._ID));
                String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB));
                String gen = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER));
                String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD));

                newUser.setUserId(id+"");
                newUser.setUserName(user);
                newUser.setDateOfBirth(date);
                newUser.setGender(gen);
                newUser.setPassword(pass);

                list.add(newUser);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList readAllInfo(String userId, String userName){

        String selection;
        String[] args = {""};

        if(userId == null){

            selection = UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME + " LIKE ?";
            args[0] = userName;
        }
        else
        {
            selection = UserProfile.Users._ID + " = ?";
            args[0] = userId;
        }

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {

                UserProfile.Users._ID,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER,
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD
        };



        String sortOrder = UserProfile.Users._ID + " DESC";

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
                UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                selection,
                args,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );

        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                User newUser = new User();

                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users._ID));
                String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_USERNAME));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_DOB));
                String gen = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_GENDER));
                String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD));

                newUser.setUserId(id+"");
                newUser.setUserName(user);
                newUser.setDateOfBirth(date);
                newUser.setGender(gen);
                newUser.setPassword(pass);

                list.add(newUser);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public int deleteInfo(String username){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = UserProfile.Users._ID + " = ?";
        String[] args = {username};

        int deletedRows = sqLiteDatabase.delete(UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME, selection, args);

        return deletedRows;
    }
}
```